# What is the maximum difference in time the pedestrian and the cyclist arrive to Y?

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving

The distance between cities $X$ and $Y$ is equal to $21$ kilometers. A pedestrian leaves $X$ and goes to $Y$ at a constant speed of $5$ kilometers per hour. At the same moment, a cyclist leaves $Y$ and goes towards $X$, the speed of the latter can vary between $10$ and $13$ km/h throughout the journey. After meeting each other, the motorcyclist goes $26$ minutes more towards city $X$, and then turns back and returns to $Y$. What is the maximum difference in time the pedestrian and the cyclist arrive to $Y$? Express the answer in minutes.

1 hour (h) = 60 minutes (min);
1 kilometer (km) = 1000 meters (m)

Comment: Question is worded in an interesting way.  Superficially, you could assume that since the pedestrian's time is fixed, you want to minimize the time taken by the cyclist.  This is true, only if you assume that the cyclist arrives first.  Alternatively, if it is possible for the pedestrian to arrive first, you then have to consider maximizing the time taken by the cyclist.  Then, you have to compare the two approaches, choosing the option that maximizes the absolute value of the difference in times.

Comment: My 1st guess, which might not be correct, is that the cyclist's time is minimized if he goes as fast as possible, until he meets the cyclist.  Then he goes as slow as possible for 26 minutes.  Then, he turns around and then once again goes as fast as possible.  As part of this guess, I would guess that the time is maximized if the cyclist exactly reverses this strategy, going slow, then fast for 26 minutes, then slow again.  ...see next comment

Comment: Two things to note: [1] With each strategy in the previous note, you have to verify that the cyclist will be able to go 26 minutes at the corresponding speed, without reaching city X. [2] I just provided guesses.  You must prove that these guesses are correct.

Comment: As your question is worded, it is likely to receive negative reactions from mathSE reviewers in the form of downvotes &/or votes to close.  If you wish to avoid this negative reaction, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the cyclist will arrive first, as in the worst case scenario when he goes $10$ km/h, then $13$ km/h, he will be less then $20$ km $\left(14+\frac{26\cdot13}{60}\right)$away while the pedestrian will be more than $10$ km $\left(14-\frac{26\cdot5}{60}\right)$ away. Thus, the cyclist should go as fast as possible, meet the pedestrian, go as slow as possible, turn back and go as fast as possible.